# HL7 SIU 2.5 specification - does it allow multiple patient?

Tags: hl7-v2

I'm working with schedule part of HL7 (SIU v2.5), more precisely I'm working on implementing unsollicited messages from a filler application.

The standard gives exemples of simple unsollicited messages (1 location resource, 1 personel resource and 1 patient) and mention possible multiplicity of location and personel resource. Although no mention of possible multiple patient.

Since my filler application can have appointment with multiple patient and resources I'm wondering if it would be a good idea to include multiple patient to unsollicited message. 
AFAIK no recommendation has been done in SIU standard in this regards. Is it allowed? Is it recommended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The patient group is optional repeating. So you can have 0 or many patients. I would check with the recipient of your appointments if they can handle multiple patients per message. Just because it is possible syntax-wise does not say what limits the receiver imposes. If you are developing for the shelf, you are free to decide. But a look at potential receivers might help.